# Managing image storage in Twillio

Tags: twilio

I am adding support for MMS in an application via the Twilio API.  I have it working but am concerned about the storage costs on Twilio.  What are the best practices for deleting images.  I have found API calls to get message history and a message by message way to delete the messages.  Is there a way to make a call to see all the stored images and their dates?  Is there a call to delete all images older than a certain date?

Answer (score 0):

Twilio Sales Engineer here. 
At this time we dont have any API calls to get all stored media on Twilio, there is also no call to delete all images over x date period.
Depending on how your app has been architected its typically better to grab the media URL, download to your server and then issue the delete command initiated from the Twilio request to your server when a new message comes in.

An MMS message has a few things that separate it from a regular SMS message.
First, the POST request will contain `NumMedia`, which will tell you the number of media files connected to this message.
Also, the MessageSID `MessageSid` will start `MM` and an SMS message will start `SM`

An example would be:

MMS Messages comes into Twilio -> Twilio reaches out to your URL -> Your script downloads the media, saves to disk, places delete request into job queue -> 200 response sent back to Twilio